# SpringBoot database embedded database driver Exception JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I have this exception when i try to start my spring boot application. I have added mysql-connector-java and spring-boot-starter-jdbc dependencies and have no idea what do not work.

```
Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

**EDIT 1**
This is my maven config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**EDIT 2**
This here is data source config

```
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hcharts");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
    }

}
```

Comment: Given your error, it seems that no embedded is either defined by your profile, or your database isn't specified. This could be useful to have some code sample to help you figure this out, especially on spring boot configuration.

Comment: If you use maven/gradle, can you please share the configuration file?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: The build configuration file isn't enough. So could you share some of the Spring configuration for the database

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `@Configuration` annotation on your `DatasourceConfig.java` file.

I tried with the annotation and `mvn spring-boot:run` starts up fine.  Without the annotation I get the text you had indicated followed by a huge stacktrace:

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START                                                                                                                           > [26/818]
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
>
> Action:
>
> If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may ne$
>   d to active it (no profiles are currently active).

Here is my `my/DatasourceConfig.java`:

```
package my.config;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hcharts");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
    }

}
```

The application will also start up, without the `@Configuration`, if you add a dependency to a known embedded database like `hsqldb`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```